# Discord bot can't send more than two emojis

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am currently working on my discord bot that works a lot with emojis. But somehow I can not let my bot write more than two emojis.

This works:

```js
case 'test':
embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor(hexColor)
  .setDescription(`Two Emoji <:harold:620608308910358530> <a:nice:634785041762877441> ok.`)
message.channel.send(embed);
break;
```

The Emojis get displayed in the discord chat as usual.

However, if I do it with more emojis, like:

```js
case 'test':
embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor(hexColor)
  .setDescription(`Three Emoji <:harold:620608308910358530> <:harold:620608308910358530>  <a:nice:634785041762877441> ok.`)
message.channel.send(embed);
break;
```

Discord automatically converts the bot's message to this:

`Three Emoji :harold: :harold: :nice: ok.`

So not the actual emojis are displayed anymore, just their names with `:` around them.

This prevents me including more than two custom emojis in a single message. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? Or is this just a known limitation from Discord's side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with custom emojis, it is best to fetch the custom emojis before using it.

```js
case 'test':
const haroldEmoji = client.emojis.cache.get('620608308910358530')
const niceEmoji = client.emojis.cache.get('634785041762877441')

embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor(hexColor)
  .setDescription(`Three Emoji ${haroldEmoji} ${haroldEmoji} ${niceEmoji} ok.`)
message.channel.send(embed);
break;
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried using this in another case before. But it turned out it is especially important to use the emoji with your notation (`${haroldEmoji}`). Just adding it in a string (`"a" + haroldEmoji`) will **not** work and only output the name or ID. This is what threw me off there.
Thank you very much again.